# Rails: preventing someone from spamming a form by hitting form route path again and again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a rails model called `ProficiencyTest` for which I have a `uniqueness` validation for the `email` field of the person taking the test.

There is a page where the user fills out there information,

then once that information is entered, and the email is validated as unique, it , calls `ProficiencyTest.create` and renders the test path.

The test path shows a simple form, and upon completion of the form the `update_attributes` is called on the `@proficiency_test` at the id created by `create`, the changes are stored by `@proficiency_test.save`, the ActionMailer sends an email to the apposite recipients of the test result, and finally a third view is rendered which basically displays test results.

This works great, under normal circumstances, if someone logs in to take the tests on Page 1, and they have already logged in, Page 1 is re-rendered with the `flash.now` set to display validation errors.

The problem is, it is very easy to simulate someone (or a web bot) spamming the form by simply navigating Back on the browser to  Page 2 where the form is presented and hit submit again which triggers another submit and fires the ActionMailer successfully.

Here is a version of my `ProficiencyTest` controller:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce169784c7889d6543c6

And here is my ProficiencyTest model:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a971ce8a2d75190f9486

How can I ensure that once a proficiency_test of a single id has been saved from the first `update_attributes` that the submit button on Page 2 doesn't trigger another save and another call to `ActionMailer`?

Comment: Can you spell out the business logic more plainly? You have a test you want people to be able to take only once, and they get an email only when that test is completed?

Comment: Can one person take only one test one time, or can people take many tests but only one time each test?

Comment: @Andrew re: your first question. That is correct. It is a test that only should be taken once by a specific person (represented by a unique email). re: second question, there is only one test. Many people can take it, but each person (test -taker) should be unique. Does that clarify the logic?

Comment: Do you want the email sent after the test is taken, or when the test is created?

Comment: after it is taken, so after the `update_attributes` is performed exactly once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the simplest way to think of this is that you should be sending the mailer in response to a model state change, not an HTTP request. So when someone hits "submit" or hits the back button and submit again, they are triggering a new HTTP request, but not necessarily a model state change.

I see from your code shown above your actually triggering the mailer in the `ProficiencyTest#grade` method. Generally speaking it's not good practice to trigger outside actions like that in a model method, particularly not one you mean to be idempodent.

I think what would work better for you is to take the mailer callbacks and such out of the model and put them into the controller, then to write your controller method such that the test can only be submitted once. So your method should look more like this:

```
  def grade
    @proficiency_test = ProficiencyTest.find(params[:id])
    if @proficiency_test.level # the test was already taken
      # redirect back or show error message
    else
      @proficiency_test.update_attributes(proficiency_test_params)
      @proficiency_test.grade! # this should grade and save the test, but not do mailers
      # send mailers here
      # redirect or render success view here
    end
  end
```

As for sending your mailers, you can make this a lot cleaner if you extract that out of your model. You could, for example, simply pass the proficiency test object into those mailers, and then read the properties off the proficiency test in your mailer actions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you say "it's not good practice to trigger outside actions like that in a model method"?

Comment: @Andrew re: refactoring the mailer logic outside of the model, you are referring to all of the `case` logic in the current `grade` function?

Comment: @Thalatta for reading, "The Rails 4 Way" is a good place to start. @B Seven, consider separation of concerns. The models job is to map data to the database. The controllers job is to pipe data between pieces of the system in response to user action. So the controller is a more appropriate place for those mailers to be triggered.